# Padding silence at the end of wav file to 160 octet frame

Tags: java, file-io, wav, outputstream, javasound

I have an issue in playing of wav files where the player sends RTP stream over the network. The last byte of the wave file that is sent is padded with 00 00 00… to make it a 172 byte packet. These extra padding causes a click sound at the end of file when heard. To avoid this click sound, I need to pad wave files with silence (instead of 00 00 00). Padding needs to be in such a way that it creates a full 160 octet frame at the end of file to avoid player adding zeroes.

I need to write a small utility program to do so. I have explored the java sound api and I have pretty much found out to append a wav file with another file or to create a new wav file by writing bits to output stream.

I need help on how do i write silence to the end of wav file to make it a full 160 octet frame. Also, I can't pad 0s to add silence should i write 0xff to create silence?

Kindly assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The PCM value for silence is 0!

I don't know anything about RTP streaming, so, take this with some scepticism. I suspect the problem isn't the padding itself (if it is truly just a string of 0's), but the transition from the actual wav to the padding.

If the wav is sounding at the end, then the abrupt transition to 0 could be the problem. You may need to provide some sort of volume tapering in place of the abrupt jump to 0 values.

Does the decoding of RTP provide a clean way to recognize the end of the wav transmission?